# What‘s the meaning of "riding shotgun with sb."?

Tags: word-meaning

What‘s the meaning of "riding shotgun with sb."?

[image]

> ride shotgun
>   1. To guard a person or thing while in transit.
>   2. Slang To ride in the front passenger seat of a car or truck.

But it seems they are not all sitting in the front passenger seat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[To ride shotgun](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/riding-shotgun.html) now means to ride in the front passenger seat of a car.  If a group of friends are headed toward a car, someone might shout out, "Shotgun!" and thereby lay claim to the front passenger seat (as opposed to a potentially cramped back seat.)

The origin of the phrase is apparently from *movies about the Old West* as opposed to the actual time of stagecoaches and the like.  A man in the passenger seat, carrying a shotgun, would guard the stagecoach as it carried valuables.  I can't find anything terribly authoritative, but it appears that such people were once called "shotgun messengers," but that nobody really referred to "riding shotgun" until 1919.  It stuck around through Hollywood and now is a reasonably common idiom.

*Riding shotgun* can now also mean to assist someone, for example, with a project.  Suppose a manager assigned a relatively inexperienced employee to complete a project for training purposes.  She might ask someone with more experience to ride shotgun on the project - to advise and assist as needed, but not to control it.

None of the people in your image appear to be riding in the front seat, but here Paul Begala (political wonk / commentator) is the important person in the car.  Whoever wrote this is pointing out that they rode with him.  It's not the normal usage of the phrase, but it works.

Comment: Perhaps the person riding shotgun took the photo?